# Closed sets , with non-empty derived sets , that are subgroup of $(\mathbb R,+)$

Tags: real-analysis, group-theory

How to find all those closed sets in $\mathbb R$ which have at least one limit-point and is a subgroup of $(\mathbb R,+)$ ?

Answer (score 1):

It is a relatively easy exercise to show that a subgroup of $(\mathbb R,+)$ is either discrete or dense.  This shouldn't allow for too many possibilities.